# Combining data from multiple sheets with Sheet Name (various names) from each as column A into one main Google Sheet [Google Apps Script]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, py-appscript

I have multiple sheets with various names on a Google Sheets document. They are all various names etc.

I'm trying to collate them into one main Google Sheet, with the name of each Sheet as Column A in the main sheet.

Here's an example of the sheet I've been working on.

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w7jvcZdF7AK4SZICyzH9YLyIz7p7lhy2YHvDbdgFA60/edit?usp=sharing](https://stackoverflow.com)

I've been messing around and I found someone's formula to do this (but it only bring in the first couple of columns from each sheet, and I'd need to manually create all the various sheet names.

You can see the formula in the Keyword Sheet in A1.

I'd ideally only want the first 6 results from each sheet.

Can anyone please help with this.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a formula. The sheet you're providing cannot be modified nor copied, so I cannot test it. Please do it, and provide feedback and open the edition if necessary:

```
    =IFNA(REDUCE("Keyword",TOCOL(A:A,1),LAMBDA(a,v,VSTACK(a,
BYROW(INDIRECT(v&"!1:6"),LAMBDA(each,{v,each}))))))
```

Change 1:6 to the range you actually need

---

It had an extra paréntesis, the output is in your sheet, looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I changed that now.

I tried your formula - but couldn't work it out.

Comment: It had an extra parenthesis,  check the update of my answer and your sheet